# In which cases can I use indentations in python?

Tags: python, indentation

I was reading [Python Language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html).

On [lexical analysis page](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation)

> Before the first line of the file is read, a single zero is pushed on the stack; this will never be popped off again. The numbers pushed on the stack will always be strictly increasing from bottom to top. At the beginning of each logical line, the line’s indentation level is compared to the top of the stack. If it is equal, nothing happens. If it is larger, it is pushed on the stack, and one INDENT token is generated.

Here, it says that adding indent on a line will just add the value associated with INDENT to the indent tracking stack.

---

So I tried to do python equivalent of the C++ snippet

```
int x = 23;
{
    int y = 13;
}
int z = 2*x;
```

with this python snippet

```
x = 23
    y = 13
z = 2*x
```

But making python run this code generated following error:

```
    y = 13
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

---

So the above rule doesn't apply all the time, I wanted to know

- Is there a python equivalent to the above C++ code snippet
- What exactly are the cases in python, when I can use the indentation,
  other than the general cases like function and class definitions.

Comment: There is no direct equivalent to that in Python because python doesn't really have block scoping.

Comment: it sounds like you did not read far enough in to the python docs, if you keep going you will understand when indenting is needed

Comment: You use indentation to indicate inclusion in a block. However, there are no "anonymous" blocks in Python, only blocks introduced by `class`, `with`, `for`, `while`, `if`, etc.

Comment: Is there something like temporary variable which I can dump it quickly after using?

Comment: In python you cannot do that like in C/C++, in those languages you can use `{ }` to limit the scope of your code, but python only understand your code based into identation since he is a interpreted language and not compiled and do not use `{ }`, basically identation is everything in python :)

Comment: I recommend you take a look at this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)), about scope, I think that will help you understand a little bit better how python works

Comment: There are a lot of other facilities in python that often make 'temporary variable' unnecessary. You're probably better off going through some more tutorial-structured material for that stuff, though, rather than trying to chew through the reference manual. There are a lot of fairly complicated details the ref docs cover that you don't really interact with directly in typical use.

Comment: @pvg thanks for the advice, I was going through it so that I could be able to think how things internally happen in python, any advice on how to be able to do that quickly?

Comment: I'd really start with something more tutorially, even if it's on more complicated  topics. Python is highly accessible but it is not, under the surface, simple. So if you're coming from C++ which is neither accessible nor simple, you might feel it doesn't matter where you start but in the case of Python, you're going to have an easier time if you get a bit of a feel of how python is written in practice before diving into the many zany details.

Comment: "Here, it says that adding indent on a line will just add the value associated with INDENT to the indent tracking stack." - yes, it does that. "So the above rule doesn't apply all the time" - yes, it does apply all the time. The fact that you got an error from the code **does not contradict that**. The resolution is simple: an `INDENT` token is **not permitted at that point** in the code. Reading the documentation about the technical details of how the language is implemented, is a **terrible** way to learn how to write correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"At the beginning of each logical line, the line’s indentation level is compared to the top of the stack. If it is equal, nothing happens. If it is larger, it is pushed on the stack, and one INDENT token is generated."

So here it tells you all about when indent token are generated. Now you also need to know that only the key words class, def, if, for, while, etc. allows you to have an additionnal current indent token.

"when I can use the indentation, other than the general cases like function and class definitions". -> Never.

Note : breaking line doesn't count as indent token. So :

```
>>> a = [1, 2, \  # \ is breaking line.
        3]
```

is possible, it doesn't technically count as indentation because it's the same python line. Same for function arguments :

```
>>> a = np.array([0,1],
                 dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important usage of indentations is in loops. Because python does not have an `end` for loops like in Matlab, the lines with the correct indentation are in the loop.